# keras ImageDataGenerator.flow with color_mode

Tags: python, image, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I am using python with keras, and wish to use keras image pre processing, some of my images are rgb while some are grayscale, I need to read all of them and changing the dimension of the grayscale images to x,x,3 or disposing them, and would like to do it as a part of the .flow function the same way I could use color_mode with .flow_from_directory, than can be set to rgb and read all the images as rgb even when they are grayscale,
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it as part of `.flow` because that assumes you already have loaded an prepared your images into a 4D tensor. You can use the [load_img](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/85f0b0b7cd0a7fa8c96a1302ce2522982763d06c/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L468) function which the `.flow_from_directory` uses that actually consumes the `color_mode` argument:

```
img = load_img(os.path.join(self.directory, fname),
               color_mode=self.color_mode,
               target_size=self.target_size,
               interpolation=self.interpolation)
```

This is from the [flow_from_directory](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/85f0b0b7cd0a7fa8c96a1302ce2522982763d06c/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L1955) code. You can use this function to load your images and then call `.flow`.

Comment: Will it load grayscale images, correctly represented as rgb 3d array?

Comment: Yes, it should.